# Need help for first angular 2 app not able to display data of an object

Tags: angular

Frist of all I'm a beginner in Angular 2 and learning it from the official website using tutorials and documentation below is the code:-

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}  

const HEROES: Hero[] = [
  { id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice' },
  { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
  { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
  { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
  { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
  { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
  { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
  { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
  { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
  { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template:`
  <h1>{{ top }}</h1>
  <h2>My Heroes</h2>
  <ul class="heroes">
    <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
      <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div>
    <label>name: </label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name">
  </div>
`
})


export class AppComponent {
  top = 'Tour of Heroessss';
  heroes = HEROES;
}
```

when the code is compiled I'm not able to display the name as well the  tag(using interpolation) only bullets and  is displayed.

Have also tried to add the entire object in the AppComponent Class but still the same result.

The project does not contain any code .html or .css file and haven't changed any code in 'app.component.spec.ts' or 'app.module.ts' or 'index.ts'.

Anyone does know what actually I'm missing.

Comment: `heroes:Hero[]=HEROES;` Try this. Do you get value for `{{top}}`?

Comment: you can not use `hero` inside `<input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name">` as its out side `ngFor`. To use it you need to define `hero` property for `AppComponent`.  is there any error you are getting ?

Comment: @micronyks "heroes:Hero[]=HEROES;" didn't worked have tried that and  neither got the value of {{top}}

Comment: @ranakrunal9 not getting any error during or after compilation in terminal but in browser console it shows 8 error "EXCEPTION: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:10:11 caused by: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" and 7 more

Comment: provide a plunker link

Comment: @ranakrunal9 you are right 'hero' from *ngFor cant accessed outside the loop  than how to access that

Comment: Check `AppComponent` in my answer i have added `hero = HEROES[0]` in it to set `hero` as component property.

Comment: @RavinderKumar (https://plnkr.co/edit/UEy1rPMUsvl67vDwRQIX) haven't updated the description due to low internet speed

Answer (score 1):

Your component and module should be as below :

```
import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core'
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'

export class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}  

const HEROES: Hero[] = [
  { id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice' },
  { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
  { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
  { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
  { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
  { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
  { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
  { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
  { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
  { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template:`
  <h1>{{ top }}</h1>
  <h2>My Heroes</h2>
  <ul class="heroes">
    <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
      <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div>
    <label>name: </label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name">
  </div>
`
})    
export class AppComponent {
  top: string = 'Tour of Heroessss';
  heroes : Hero[] = HEROES;

  // You need to set hero property
  hero: Hero = HEROES[0];
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Doesn't work check this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/TedzlcqmVOXkqugwNbsM?p=preview) let me know what did i miss. @ranakrunal9

Comment: Check https://plnkr.co/edit/tj706CXq1AOmFe1J1D9r?p=preview and i have updated my answer.

Comment: Only difference between your code mine was `FormsModule`.  Can you explain what is the need of `FormsModule`

Comment: to use `ngModel` we need to import `FormsModule`.

Comment: That makes sense. I was getting error related to  ngModel. I will look into `FormsModule`. Thanks

Comment: @ranakrunal9 want to display all the names at once

Comment: @ranakrunal9 what's the point of adding NgModule and AppModule class as they are already part of app.module.ts in which we are already importing our app.component.ts

Comment: here i have updated my answer as per your `plnkr` but in application all your `module` and `component` will be in different folders as per your application folder structure.

Comment: @ranakrunal9 got your point but how to display all the names at once as local 'hero' variable is not accessible outside the *ngFor loop

Comment: @ranakrunal9 an unusual thing came to notice just by removing the <div> of <input> it worked flawlessly what might be reason behind it? **asynchronous nature**

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try for the following things:

- First, declare the top and heroes as **public** (inside AppComponent)
- If first doesn't works, remove the let(from the ngFor and use **#**)
  Eg:  ***ngFor="# hero of heroes"**

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**: The problem lies in this div

```
  <div>
    <label>name: </label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name">
  </div>
```

As someone has mentioned, you can't use `hero.name` here because this div is already outside the `*ngFor` directive.

**The Full Story/Working Code**

Seems like you're adding on code to the previous part of the tutorial. However, the previous part there was only one hero specified. Since we have replaced `hero` with `heroes` in the `.ts` file, we need to change to code so that we can still access the information of `hero`.

If you take out your code that I have extracted above and run, then it will work. Here's a similar one.

```
<h2>My Heroes</h2>
<div>
    <ul class="heroes">
        <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
            <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If you want to include the input boxes then we need to use a repeater directive again `*ngFor="let hero of heroes"` as such:

```
<h2>My Heroes</h2>
<div>
    <ul class="heroes">
        <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
            <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<li *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
    <div>
        <label for="name"></label>
        <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" type="text" placeholder="name"/>
    </div>
</li>
```